# application context url giving 404 after deployment in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, deployment, http-status-code-404

I have an application deployed on tomcat 7.0.36 in eclipse for dev. Tomcat is configured to hot-redeploy when I make changes to the application. This application uses JPA with Hibernate as the provider and MySQL 5. However as soon as I build a war and deploy to a standalone tomcat, the application get the:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

while trying to connect to the same database with the same credential defined in the persistence.xml file.

One other problem is that on a different machine with different credentials, the connection is successful, except that when visiting the application context url, i keep getting a `404`. First I thought it might be a tomcat related issue, so i tried deploying to jetty 7...same result.

I changed the header of the `web.xml` file to be Servlet 3.0 instead of 2.5, but that did solve the problem.

Comment: what does servlet spec version have to do with this...? and how is the connection successful if you've never even activated your app? you should really try to put one issue into one question and preferrably provide a reproducable test case + steps.

Comment: 1-the connection is successful because on application deployment i can see the hibernate logs as it connects and drop-create the tables.

Comment: 1-the connection is successful because on application redeployment i can see the hibernate logs as it connects and drop-create the tables at application start up. 2- you are right, they are 2 issues here and there should be a separate question for each. 3- I suspected that servlet version might be an issue as the JPA version is 2.0 and thus should be deployed on servlet 3.0 implementation such as tomcat 3.0 or jetty 7 or 8. In my case, for tomcat at  least, not even the default welcome tomcat page show up. Any advice on how to approach this problem?

Comment: well, start with the password issue. make sure you know which credentials you're using, test using those with mysql client outside your app and continue from there - the same user/pass cannot fail for one app and work on another.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the OS is windows...perhaps it's file permission issue or some such. When I run my app in eclipse, it connects successfully, but when i drop the war in the webapp dir and start tomcat from the command line, it fails to connect